# CSS centering text between two images

Tags: css, centering

I need to display two images and some text like so:

```
------------------------------------------
img1--------some centered text-------img2
------------------------------------------
```

- img1 and img2 are not the same dimensions, but their widths are very close
- The text is variable depending on the page in which it is displayed, and may include two lines instead of one.
- The text needs to centered horizontally between the two images, or between the outside of the container (either will be fine)
- the text AND the images need to be **centered vertically** within the container.

I can do this VERY easily with a table, but I'd rather not retreat to that for layout. The `position:inline-block` and `display:table-cell` attributes work great in some browsers, but I need to support IE6+.

Answer (score 4):

```
<style type="text/css">
#image1 { float: left; }
#image2 { float: right; }
#text { text-align: center; }
</style>
```

Comment: That takes care of the horizontal component, but everything is top-aligned. I need everything to center vertically, as well.

Comment: In order to do the vertical alignment, you are going to have to set heights on the image and text containers.  Then you can use vertical-align:center;

Comment: Attempted using vertical-align on a div, a span and an image with no effect.

Comment: vertical-align uses "middle" not "center"