# Unable to center text between two images

Tags: css

I'm using the technique in Stack Overflow question [CSS centering text between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008612/css-centering-text-between-two-images) but am unable to make the text center.

I would like the text "0 of 0" centered in this markup ([as a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5jQd/2/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="invoiceImageContainer">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8QT8u.png" id="invoiceImage">
    <div id="invoiceNav">
        <img title="Next" src="http://i.imgur.com/oZb7r.png" id="nextInvoice">
        <img title="Previous" src="http://i.imgur.com/aKi11.png" id="prevInvoice">
        <span id="invoiceCount">0 of 0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#invoiceImageContainer{
    width:420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#invoiceImage {
    height:600px;
}
#invoiceNav {
    color:black;
    font-size:10pt;
}
#prevInvoice {
    float:left;
    padding-left:100px;
}
#nextInvoice {
    float:right;
    padding-right:100px;
}
#invoiceCount {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Your span needs to be a block element. Change it to a [div] or assign [display: block] property to the span class. http://jsfiddle.net/conekt/W5jQd/18/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `span` for the text container which is an inline element. Therefore its width is the same as the width required for its content, changing it to a `p` (or changing `display` to block) will allow for horizontal centering. If you want to center vertically then set the `line-height` equal to the height of the images and set `vertical-align: middle`.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W5jQd/3/.

Answer (score 1):

Good old quick hack:

```
#invoiceImageContainer{
    width:420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#invoiceImage {
    height:600px;
}
#invoiceNav {
    color:black;
    font-size:10pt;
    text-align:center;
}
#prevInvoice {
    float:left;
    padding-left:100px;
}
#nextInvoice {
    float:right;
    padding-right:100px;
}
#invoiceCount
{
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

In your original markup you had #invoiceCount set to text-align:center. This is wrong because you can't center spans in that way, so I moved it to your container div.

The quick hack is the line-height, set to approximately the known size of your image. This technique is good and safe when you are doing a single line of text and the size of the elements involved is known.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
/* should be block level element */
#invoiceCount{
    display: block;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/W5jQd/5/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that  doesn't support "width", since it's an inline block.  The following changes will do the trick: in HTML change `<span id="invoiceCount">0 of 0</span>` to `<div id="invoiceCount">0 of 0</div>` and in CSS add `width` to the `#invoiceCount` like this:

```
#invoiceCount {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to the CSS of #invoiceNav

```
text-align: center;
line-height: 32px;
```

the first centers the `<span>` element and the second centers the text vertically in the `<div>` (same height as the images)